# How to use the "..." parameters in a user defined function

Tags: r

I'm trying to understand the "..." function within function calls, now I have a function say `function(x,...)`, I though any variables passed to it after `x` (the `...` ) would be used within the function or passed to it's subfunctions?

For e.g my code below. I would expect an output of "fac_ed", "single", class(x) but only class(x) gets outputted, what is wrong?

Code

```
  set.Class  <- function (x, ...) tryCatch( { class(x)  <- c(..., "class(x)") }, 

                                  error = function(ex) {

                                              class(x)  <- c(..., "query", "data.frame")

                                            } )

set.Class(SMA.grouped,"fac_ed", "single")
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the `...` argument. Did you mean to return `x` from your function? Because otherwise changes to the class will only happen inside the function.

Comment: Yes that is fully correct. Thank you!